# Gitlab + Jenkins Intergration Over Private IP (Amazon EC2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, gitlab

I'm running both my Jenkins & GitLab server on two difference EC2 instances.

Is there away that I can grant GitLab access an integration with my Jenkins over my Jenkins private ip address?

Comment: Are those instances running in the same VPC? If yes, you just need to check security groups and use the AWS provided private IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well all i had to do is over the gitlab admin panel settings> network> allow local communication.

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. check info your two  intances, if Subnet ID and Availability zone in two intance are similar, you can access private ip.

[image]

2. if Subnet ID and Availability zone in two intance are not similar. I can access public ip:

2.1 Security Groups > create sercurity group > config public ip your two instance.

2.2 then EC2 > Instances > your instances_name > Actions > Security > Change security groups > Add sercurity group you create in step 2.1 > Save. Now you can access public ip your two instance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Building on David Eden's answer just with a picture.
[image]